# Leaflet Markercluster - "this._featureGroup.addEventParent is not a function"

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.markercluster

I am adding [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin to my existing [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map.

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: `this._featureGroup.addEventParent` is not a function

In relation to the line `var locations = L.markerClusterGroup();`.

I cannot find any information about what this error might mean.

I am linking to the Markercluster JS file, and after Leaflet. Not sure why else it would not be able to find a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the error you get when you use Leaflet version < 1 (e.g. `0.7.7`) with Leaflet.markercluster version 1+ (e.g. `1.0.0`)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z6bc79dq/

As mentioned on the plugin [home page](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#leafletmarkercluster):

> Requires Leaflet 1.0.0
>
> For a Leaflet 0.7 compatible version, use the leaflet-0.7 branch

(Leaflet.markercluster version [`0.5.0`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/releases/tag/v0.5.0) is the latest compatible with Leaflet `0.7.x`)

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error when I tried to add invalid layers (via the cluster group `addLayers` method) to a cluster group. (I was trying to add markers to a cluster group but the markers were not actually markers).

Hope this helps someone

Comment: What's your solution of it? `Also got this error` is not an answer imho.

Comment: The supposed `markers` that I was adding to the cluster group were not actually `marker` instances but were something else. Check that the layers you are adding via `addLayers` are actually layers