# ERROR TypeError: layer.addEventParent is not a function while setting markers for marker cluster in angular

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using ngx-leaflet-markercluster in angular for showing cluster of markers sharing same location.While setting markers ,it gives error addeventparent is not a function .

//ts

```
const data: Marker[] = res.map(loc => {
      if (loc.STATUS === this.appConstantsService.OUTAGE_STATUS.INACTIVE) {
        return { lat: loc.location_details_lat, lon: loc.location_details_lon, icon: '/assets/icons/marker-0.png' };

      } else {
        return { lat: loc.location_details_lat, lon: loc.location_details_lon, icon: 'assets/icons/marker-1.png' };
      }
});
this.markerClusterData = data;
```

//html

```
<div leaflet style="height: 600px;" 
[leafletOptions]="options"
[leafletBaseLayers]="baseLayers"

[leafletMarkerCluster]="markerClusterData"
[leafletMarkerClusterOptions]="markerClusterOptions"
(leafletMarkerClusterReady)="markerClusterReady($event)"
>
</div>
```

I want markers to appear in cluster when it have same lat and long ,and when I click the cluster it should zoom in and show the markers.First I was working with agm map.I got an issue when two markers share same lat and long .I used agm-marker-cluster and agm-maker-spider but there was no solution in it.Is there any other way to solve it

Comment: which versions are you using (leaflet / markercluster) ? 
there could be a conflict there, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028929/leaflet-markercluster-this-featuregroup-addeventparent-is-not-a-function

Comment: @rebecca  "@types/leaflet": "^1.4.6",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.0"

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but shoudlnt you use the the marker class to instantiate the markers: marker([long, lat], configObject)?

Comment: also, as far as i understand, you need to use addLayer() to add a marker? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333263/leaflet-markerclustergroup

Comment: @rebecca Yeah your right marker class must be used for adding markers .I want to show customized information window for every marker .every marker has different data.Can It be done

Comment: @Karthi you showed versions for your _typings_, not for the JS libraries Leaflet and Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: @ghybs Its working .I have to use marker class for adding markers

Comment: @Qellson why the markers are placed bit far from spider line when markers are spiderifies..

Answer (score 0):

We have to use  marker class for adding markers

```
const data: Marker[] = res.map(loc => {
    if (loc.STATUS === this.appConstantsService.OUTAGE_STATUS.INACTIVE) {
        const icon = L.icon({ iconUrl: '/assets/icons/marker-0.png' });
        return marker([loc.location_details_lat, loc.location_details_lon], { icon });
    } else {
        const icon = L.icon({ iconUrl: '/assets/icons/marker-1.png' });

        return marker([loc.location_details_lat, loc.location_details_lon], { icon })
    }
});
```