# Leaflet error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: layer.addEventParent is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary, leaflet

Leaflet clusterGroup doesnt works, im catching this error Leaflet error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: layer.addEventParent is not a function

```
const markerClusters = new MarkerClusterGroup();
const clusters = [];
const markers = [];
const customIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41]
});

onMounted(()=>{
    markerClusters.clearLayers();
    toRaw(props.coordinatesTwo).forEach((item)=> {
        let marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(item.coordinates.lat, item.coordinates.lng), {
            icon: customIcon
        })
        markers.push(marker)
        //markerClusters.addLayer(marker);
    })
    markerClusters.addLayer(markers)
    //console.log(markers);
    props.map.leafletObject.addLayer(markerClusters);
})
```

Comment: Have you seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028929/leaflet-markercluster-this-featuregroup-addeventparent-is-not-a-function)?

Answer (score 0):

The addLayer() method of MarkerClusterGroup expects a **single layer object** or **an array of layer objects as an argument**. In your code, you are passing an array of `markers` to the addLayer() method, which is causing the error.
Let's pass it to `addLayer()`, you can directly add each marker to the `markerClusters` group using the `addLayer()` method within your loop. Here's the updated code:

```js
onMounted(() => {
  markerClusters.clearLayers();
  toRaw(props.coordinatesTwo).forEach((item) => {
    let marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(item.coordinates.lat, item.coordinates.lng), {
      icon: customIcon
    });
    markerClusters.addLayer(marker);
  });

  props.map.leafletObject.addLayer(markerClusters);
});
```